# Lots of grasshoppers in the backyard

Tags: pests

My backyard has grasshoppers. Lots and lots of grasshoppers. I tend to ignore them, because it's currently a weed garden more than anything else. I tried planting a raised bed this year with some beans, chillies, cilantro, mint, and grapes, and didn't see any insect-related problems.

Reading online, it appears that grasshoppers are considered a pest.

What I'm interested in is:

1. Are they a sign of a deeper problem (just like clover indicates low-nitrogen lawns), and
2. Should I do anything about them?

In terms of species, I'm not sure what type they are; they appear greenish-brownish, with very tiny, bright-green young.

Answer (score 4):

grasshoppers absolutely can be a huge problem, haven't you ever heard the term "plague of locusts"?  if you haven't noticed damage, it doesn't mean they aren't feasting.. immature grasshoppers nymphs eat small amounts and large grasshoppers eat large amounts.

what will probably happen is that you will suddenly notice you have no cilantro, or your beans have no leaves.

grasshoppers are also kind of cyclic, one year will be a big year then you will hardly see one for a few years.

I don't know that you can really do anything about them directly though...

they do make great fishing bait...

once you tame your arid weedy landscape the grasshoppers will just disappear for the most part.

Comment: +1 for "immature grasshoppers nymphs eat small amounts and large grasshoppers eat large amounts"

Answer (score 2):

This link might be useful to you. http://www.co.missoula.mt.us/extension/plantdata/PESTS/grasshoppers/index.html

In the article they say:

> Grasshoppers breed and grow in weedy, undisturbed areas like roadside
>   ditches, fence rows, untilled pastures, and in crops that continue
>   longer than a single growing season.

You said:

> I tend to ignore them, because it's currently a weed garden more than
>   anything else.